# Reset Angular Factory Data on Each State Change

Tags: angularjs

Ok, I have a app.config.js file that sets the state provider configuration for users to click on different links and get different data depending on the state (not so important here).

Here is my table factory that represents table data/actions on the screen.

table.factory.js

```
export default function($filter){

 function Column(title, alias){
    this.title = title;
    this.alias = alias || null;
 }

 let Table = {
      expandAll: false,
      sortReverse: false,
      sortType: null,
      columns: [],
      tableData: null,
      emptyMessage: "No Data.",
      sort: function(column, index){},
      toggleRow: function(index){},
      toggleAll: function(){},
    }

    return {
       table: Table,
       column: Column
    };
}
```

As you can see, this table factory returns a literal object with 2 properties: table and column.

Here are two additional factories that uses the table.factory.js.

load_balancing_advanced_table.factory.js:

```
export default function($http, $stateParams, $filter, tableFactory){

let Table = tableFactory.table;
let Column = tableFactory.column;

Table.sortType = "site_name";
Table.emptyMessage = "No Load Balancing - Advanced Data."
Table.columns.push(
    new Column("Site Name", "site_name"), 
    new Column("VLAN", "vlan"), 
    new Column("HTTP Caching", "http_caching"), 
    new Column("HTTP to HTTPS Redirect", "redirect"),
    new Column("Fallback URL(s)", "fallback_url")
);

return Table;

}
```

virtual_machines_table.factory.js:

```
export default function($http, $stateParams, $filter, tableFactory, natTableFactory){


let Table = tableFactory.table;
let Column = tableFactory.column;

Table.totalStorageAllocation = 0.0;
Table.emptyMessage = "No Virtual Machines Data."
Table.sort = null;
Table.sortReverse = null;
Table.columns.push(
    new Column("Host"), 
    new Column("Details"), 
    new Column("Network")
);

return Table;

}
```

The reason why I have two factories using or injecting the table.factory.js is because I put the common table properties and methods in one file (the table factory is acting like the parent) and keep the code dry, so that the "child" factories do not need to add the same code.

I do understand that factories are singleton, and I thought that on each state change (when user clicks different links), the table.factory.js will go back to the intial state and then populate with the correct data depending on which controller is being used. However, it looks like that each time I switch between the load balancing page and virtual machines page (load_balancing_advanced.controller.js and virtual_machines.controller.js), the columns and data that belongs to the load balancing table are added to the virtual machines table and vice versa. The ideal scenario is on each content change, the appropriate controller will inject the "child" factory that will use the "parent" table factory.

virtual_machines.controller.js:

```
export default function($scope, $stateParams, $filter, virtualMachinesTableFactory, formFactory){

let self = this;
self.virtualMachine = virtualMachinesTableFactory;

}
```

load_balancing_advanced.controller.js:

```
export default function($scope, $stateParams, $filter, loadBalancingAdvancedTableFactory, formFactory){

let self = this;
self.loadBalancingAdvanced = loadBalancingAdvancedTableFactory;

}
```

As you can see, the controllers are simple, and all I'm doing is injecting the two factories to the controller and display the appropriate data to the view.

I guess what I'm asking, is there a way to reset the table.factory.js data? Or is there a better way?

I did a quick test, and on page reload, the table factory is being called only once while the appropriate "child" factories are being an called on each content/state change.

Here:

```
tableFactory->LoadBalancingAdvancedFactory->LoadBalancingAdvancedController
tableFactory->VirtualMachinesFactory->VirtualMachinesController
```

Comment: *"I do understand that factories are singleton"* - I don't think that statement is always the case. And this is a direct result of the NG team not following expectations in their naming convention.  `.factory( 'singleton', function(){ function Singlton(){ ... }; return new Singlton })` vs `.factory( 'notASinglton', function (){ return function Singleton(){ ... }})`.  If you return the constructor function and instantiate where injected, you get a clean slate each time.  If the NG API was named `.factoryFunc( ... )` you'd see less confusion.

Comment: I'm sorry you are completely right as before I wanted to return a constructor function, but after googling around, it wasn't a good practice?? I actaully wanted to do (inside the factory) function Table() {} return Table; Then inside the controller I would inject the factory and do new Table();

Comment: I see no difference in these two regarding the end result.  Do what's pragmatic and scalable, not what purist say. https://gist.github.com/jusopi/fa68f1b517e3b24a4c6b31d79fcfbb6c

Comment: I actually fixed the issue by returning a function constructor instead of an object literal. A function constructor returns its own object while an object literal is singleton. Is that even a good practice in the angular world?

Comment: If it works, it's clear what you're doing and you've left some documentation (e.g. comments) then I think you're doing a good job.  In other words, who cares? right?

Comment: @jusopi Thanks! Yeah, in my case, it makes sense to return a function constructor instead of an object literal for several reasons, and I will explain it later. Also, I actually lied that data is no correct when switching to different pages. The only data issue that I was having, are the columns being pushed into the array. I just needed to empty the array before pushing the new columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the table factory is just fine returning an object literal, and I lied about data not being correct. The only issue is the column property of the Table object. When switching between content, the columns kept being push to the Table.columns property. I just needed to empty the array.

```
// Load Balancing Advanced Table Factory
// The fix Table.columns = [];
Table.columns.push(
   new Column("Site Name", "site_name"), 
   new Column("VLAN", "vlan"), 
   new Column("HTTP Caching", "http_caching"), 
   new Column("HTTP to HTTPS Redirect", "redirect"),
   new Column("Fallback URL(s)", "fallback_url")
);

// Virtual Machines Table Factory
// The fix Table.columns = [];
Table.columns.push(
   new Column("Host"), 
   new Column("Details"), 
   new Column("Network")
);
```

However, instead of returning a literal object inside the table factory, I went ahead and return function constructor:

```
function Table(columns = [], emptyMessage = "No Data."){
    this.expandAll = false;
    this.sortReverse = false;
    this.sortType = null;
    this.columns = columns;
    this.tableData = null;
    this.emptyMessage = emptyMessage;
}

Table.prototype = {
    setTableData: function(tableData){},
    setSortReverse: function(sortReverse){},
    setSortType: function(sortType){},
    sort: function(){},
    toggleRow: function(index){},
    toggleAll: function(){}
}

return Table;
```

The reason I went with returning a function constructor is because if you look inside the virtual_machines_table.factory.js, I have this line of code:

```
/*
   This is a custom property and other properties and methods (omitted) 
   that belongs only to the virtual machines table, which does not exists 
   in the table factory.
   Using a table factory that returns an object literal (same object),
   the load balancing advanced table or any future tables will 
   have those custom methods and properties that belongs in the 
   virtual machines table; this is not what I wanted.
   Returning a function constructor instead will ensure on each content
   change, each table gets its own different table object. 
*/
Table.totalStorageAllocation = 0.0;
```